# Cannot change state from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am try to change state in parent component onChange event.

On click on Checkbox state `includeExtremeClaims` should be changed into `true`.

Parent Component:

```
export class ManageAnalytics extends Component {
  static contextTypes = baseContextTypes

  state = {
    includeExtremeClaims: false
  }

 handleChange = (e, { name, value } = {}) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

render() {
  return (
     <div>
        // Passing down handleChange and includeExtremeClaims state as props
        <Analytics
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          includeExtremeClaims={this.state.includeExtremeClaims}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Child Compnent:

```
export class Analytics extends Component {
  static contextTypes = baseContextTypes

render() {
    const { handleChange, includeExtremeClaims } = this.props
  return (
    <Checkbox
      label="Include Extreme Cases"
      name="includeExtremeClaims"
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={includeExtremeClaims}          
    />
   )
}
```

**Question is**: On click on Checkbox Why my state is not changed?

Comment: Sorry for the first comment, totally misread the code, I need an extra coffee this morning :( I think you should probably log what happens in `handleChange`: is it called (it is very likely) and what are the values of `name` and `value`. It is very likely that the state is updated with an empty object or something like that.

Comment: It's ok :) ok I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in value which is provide on Checkbox, value is always the same, that is reason why is not changed:

`value={includeExtremeClaims}` it should be `value={!includeExtremeClaims}`